# How to use bijection of two sets to define a bijection of their respective differences?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The identity function on a set is invertible.

So given two sets $A$ and $B$, if I have a bijection between their differences

$b':(A\setminus B)\to (B\setminus A)$

then I can extend this to a bijection

$b:A\to B$

via

$b(x):=\begin{cases} b'(x) & \mathrm{if}\ x\in A\setminus B\\\\ x & \mathrm{if}\ x\in A\cap B \end{cases}$

**Question:** In the converse situation, where I'm given a bijection $f:A\to B$, is there a canonical way to get a bijection $f':(A\setminus B)\to (B\setminus A)$?

I can imagine some function $s_f:B\to B$, which acts as permutation between $A\cap B$ and $B\setminus A$, so $(s_f\circ f')\left|_{A\setminus B}\right.$ is a bijection on the differences. But to be honest I don't even know how to show that a having a bijection $f:A\to B$ implies that the set $A\setminus B$ and $B\setminus A$ can be put in bijection. So **Question 2:** is this even true?

[image]

Comment: No. For instance, let $B$ be a countably infinite proper subset of a countably infinite set $A$.

Comment: But this is a nice question for finite $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Okay, thanks! What I try to find out with this question is actually this: If $B\subseteq A$, does the following predicate capture equinumerosity? $B≈A:=∃f. [to ∧ from]$ where $to = ∀(b ∈ B). ∃!(fb). ∃(p ∈ f). ∀x. [[x ∈ p] ↔ [x = b ∨ x = (fb)]]$ and $from=∀(a ∈ A). (a ∈ B) ∨ ∃((inva) ∈ B). ∃(p ∈ f). ∀x.[[x ∈ p] ↔ [x = (inva) ∨ x = a]]$. At the moment, this is my conclusion from the tedious work of reverse-engineering the Grothendieck-Tarski axioms in terms of primitive FOL symbols [here](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/grothprim.html). I didn't find equinumerosity defined anywhere else.

Comment: A question would then be, in general, how to capture equinumerosity of two sets in FOL, without restrictions on A and B, and without introducing ordered pairs.